TypeError at /signup/ join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'
I wanna make a sign up form:
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            login(request,user)
            
            return redirect(frontpage)
    else:
        form=UserCreationForm()
        
    return render('core/signup.html',{'form':form})

when ı running this code block it returns an error:
TypeError at /signup/ join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

how can ı fix it?

Please add the full error stacktrack so we can see which line raises the error.

I suspect the error is due to a missing argument to the render() function. The docs say it should be:
render(request, template_name, context, ...)

but you have not included that first argument request in your code:
# wrong code
return render('core/signup.html',{'form':form})

TO fix it:
return render(request, 'core/signup.html', {'form':form})

